# Component Hierarchies and Template file grouping

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm refactoring my code into components, I"m finding that component hierarchies are working well. The only issue I'm running into is with the template naming requirements. **I'd like to be able to have multiple templates in a components directory, that I can lookup dynamically**. An example below of whats working and whats not:

```
side-bar/
|__component.js
|__template.hbs
|__sidebar-links/
    |_component.js
    |_template.hbs
|_sidebar-drawer/
  |_component.js
  |_template-one.hbs
  |_template-two.hbs
  |_...
```

So -- as a simplification, my sidebar-drawer component can make use of many templates (as partials, or sometimes childViews with the `layout` property dynamically set), swapping them out based on links. I'd ideally like to group them together. Instead, to do something like this i"m forced to keep them in the `/app/templates` directory, or treat them like components.

I think I can get this working by modifying the templates compiler (found [here]):

```
app._podTemplatePatterns = function() {
  return this.registry.extensionsForType('template').map(function(extension) {
    return new RegExp(extension + '$');
  });
};
```

This compiles all templates having `hbs` extensions, regardless of location. But I'm then unable to look them up -- presumably i'd need to sub-class the Resolver as well. I'm fine to start going down that path, but a few questions:

1. Should I be hesitant about using the (seemingly) private method `_podTemplatePatterns` above?
2. Is it a bad idea to modify the resolver to accommodate this (e.g. performance impact?)
3. Any other reason this might be discouraged in ember-land?

Comment: how can you use the `sidebar-links` component? I'd love to have my components organized into a folder but I'm not able to use them in my templates when I do.

Comment: Its been a while so this may be out of date / not completely right, but I was using them like: `{side-bar/sidebar-links}`. I want to say that part is not dependent on the podTemplatePatterns / multiple templates aspect and I think what we ultimately did for that was conditionally import / use the template in the component file itself.

Comment: Yup. That does work. You create a directory/pod for `side-bar` with a `component.js` and `template.hbs` inside. Then, you can add `sidebar-links.js` to `side-bar` and call it as `{{side-bar/sidebar-links}}`. You can also just name `side-bar/sidebar-links.js` -> `side-bar/links.js` and call it as `{{side-bar/links}}`. I have a number of components that inherit from a base class and this is working well for me. But, my sub-components have very simple templates so I just inline them in the js files. I can imagine this getting a little hairy if you were putting templates in the side-bar directory.